# syncrhonise databases then reseed without race condition

Tags: database, race-condition

I'm using [ApexSQL Diff API](http://www.apexsql.com/help/apexsqldiffapi2011/HTML/webframe.html) to synchronise server and client databases with different identity seeds. After synchronisation, I reseed both databases.

There is a race condition. If the server adds new rows after synchronisation but before reseeding, they will have the wrong ID. ApexSQL manages its own database connections, so I can't synchronise inside a transaction.

Example:

1. Reseed client database to 1000.
2. Reseed server database to 0.
3. Add three rows to the client. They have ID 1000,1001,1002.
4. Add three rows to the server. They have ID 0,1,2.
5. Synchronise. The server now has rows with ID 0,1,2,1000,1001,1002.
6. Adding the client's rows have implicitly reseeded the server to 1003.
7. A row is added to the server by some other process. It has ID 1003.
8. The client reseeds the server to 3 ... too late!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with negative IDs for the clients, thereby obviating reseeding the server :-)